# Pip requirements outputting global packages

Tags: pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I have a Virtual env for my django project, but when I hit `pip freeze`, I get what must be a global site package list, includes too many packages, like ubuntu packages and so much irrelevant stuff. This happens whether virtualenv is active or not. My site packages list looks a bit slim too, so I wonder whether venv has been working at all.

```
(env)~/code/django/ssc/dev/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages> ls
django
Django-1.4-py2.7.egg-info
easy-install.pth
pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
setuptools.pth
```

What's my problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your virtual environment has access to the system's site-packages dir (ie. you used `virtualenv --system-site-packages`) then it's normal for the list to be a rather long one.

Compare the following:

```bsh
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages v1 && source v1/bin/activate
$ (v1) pip freeze | wc -l  # 100

$ virtualenv v2 && source v2/bin/activate
$ (v2) pip freeze | wc -l  # 2
```

Can you try recreating the virtualenv?

Alternatively, adding a `no-global-site-packages.txt` file should tell pip to ignore the global site-packages:

```bsh
$ touch $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python${version}/no-global-site-packages.txt
```

Comment: You mean setting up virtualenv again, and reinstalling all packages I used? I suppose I have no choice right? But I'm sure I didn't use --`system-site-packages`. I followed this: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/ Can you think why this would've happened? I will recreate the virtual env by deleting the env folder and simply starting it again. Can I check if it is using system-site-packages somehow? I guess just by checking if it includes them upon first freeze?

Comment: I've update the answer, but there really isn't anything peculiar about the process they follow in the article. Checking for a `no-global-site-packages.txt` should give you that information.

Comment: There is a `no-global-site-packages.txt` file. But my requirements file shouldn't include the likes of rhythmbox-ubuntuone==3.0.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplejson==2.3.2
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
ssh==1.7.14
system-service==0.1.6
ubuntuone-couch==0.3.0
ubuntuone-installer==3.0.2
ubuntuone-storage-protocol==3.0.2

I don't get it. I have long known that I am cursed, but this one doesn't add up.

Comment: Any luck with `pip freeze --local`? Maybe even a `sudo pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv` for good measure? It really doesn't add up.

Comment: well, i have just set up a new environment and that seems to produce a smaller, correct requirements file. I'll keep an eye on it. in the meantime, is there a way of assessing a django file for requirements aside from pip, so that i can rebuild requirements in the new environment? thanks so much for your attention!

Comment: @gvalkov thanks a lot for the [`--local`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html#cmdoption-l) option to `pip freeze`. Please include this in your answer, because I for one have been looking for it too long now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the most concise option was just left in the comments. Since I have just almost missed it I will put it here as a separate answer with some tweaks.
You can add `--local` flag with your pip freeze if you are running a virtual env with system-site-packages enables.
So, if you had:

```
py -m venv --system-site-packages env
```

To make sure you are not getting all system deps into your `requirements.txt`, just run:

```
python -m pip freeze --local > requirements.txt
```

Another, a bit more elaborate option, but still viable because dependencies are not supposed to change all that often, would be to go into pyvenv.cfg file located in your virtual env library and manually change:

```
include-system-site-packages = true/false
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me