# Save all currently installed packages in anaconda to a file

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I want to make a `.txt` file with all the python packages my environment is using, and include it in the git repo, so that anyone who needs to run the code, can just make an environment, install all the packages from the list and use it.

I have two questions, first, how can I create that `.txt` files with all the installed packages? Second, how can someone with the `.txt` file install everything from it (using pip3?) in their fresh anaconda environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a list of installed packages in a certain virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961926/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-a-certain-virtualenv)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After activating your environment, you can do this:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

And to install all these packages in a fresh environment:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, it is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: I will, but only 5 minutes have passed, so it will not allow me yet.