# Cant read csv files using pandas in Visual Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, csv

**Python** : 3.5

**IDE** : Visual code

**Platform** : win 10 64 bit

First i created a virtual env `_kerasVenv` and then activated the env and then installed `pandas` using `pip`.

This is my directory structure:

[image]

I added a python script in `Exercise files` folder where I am trying to read .csv file using pandas

```
test= pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

.csv file and python script are in the same folder so wrong path is not the issue.But i am getting below error:

```
Unable to open 'parsers.pyx': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (c:\users\anubhav.jhalani\downloads\ex_files_building_deep_learning_apps\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx)).
```

Can someone explain why python is looking for pandas in `c:\users\anubhav.jhalani\downloads\ex_files_building_deep_learning_apps` folder and why parsers.pyx file does not exist in original `pandas` folder which are in `_kerasVenv` folder?
How can i get rid of this error?

**Update**: I found out while hovering on `import pandas as pd` statement that it is looking for pandas module in `c:\users\anubhav.jhalani\downloads\ex_files_building_deep_learning_apps` . Why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to always give the total file path.

Instead of:

```
test= pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

try to use:

```
test = pd.read_csv('C:/users/anubhav.jhalani/downloads/ex_files_building_deep_learning_apps/test.csv', endcoding='utf-8')
```

this should help, you can also have a look here, what syntax you need to write it:
[Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

You can also get the full path in your windows explorer, if you are unsure where it is saved.

Comment: Tried but still same error. I found out while hovering on 'import pandas as pd' statement that it is looking for pandas module in  'c:\users\anubhav.jhalani\downloads\ex_files_building_deep_learning_apps' . It is weird to me. why it is happening?

Comment: thats an different error then, you need to install pandas in this enviorment!

Comment: it is already installed in the virtual env '_kerasVenv' and I am using this env in vscode.

Comment: did oyu check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961926/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-a-certain-virtualenv

Comment: well. I didnt understand the problem but reinstalling pandas and giving complete path of the file(even if file is in the same folder) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it also wasn't able to find the file even in the same directory and with the complete path. I figured it out that this issue was happening only in my VSCode editor and when I opened the same notebook in jupyter lab it was perfectly working. So then I tried one thing that make it work for me in VSCode as well was that I put my file in the directory other than "C". For example I put my file in the "D" directory and in VSCode it becomes able to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to VS Code settings .
2. Type "Execute" on search bar.
3. Select 'Run Code configuration' under 'Extensions'.
4. Check the checkbox 'Whether to use the directory of the file to be executed as the working directory'.

It should probably be able to read files now .