# csv file not importing in pandas using vscode.....showing "no such file or directory found"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

i was trying to import a csv file(named as bostondatasets1.csv) in pandas using vscode .i checked & modified the syntax multiple times but the terminal is still showing error. it's showing that "No such file or directory"... can someone tell me why is this happening or what's wrong in syntax...coz it's working on other's system just not in my system.

i just want the csv file to import in my python script[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb2QD.png)

Comment: try this it will help to figure out the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990772/cant-read-csv-files-using-pandas-in-visual-code

Comment: _coz it's working on other's system just not in my system_ The other person has the csv file on their computer, but you don't.

Comment: Please do not use spaces in the file name, usually sampleProject or sample_ project. The problem should be that there is a space in front of the csv file in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your screenshot .There is a little issue with the path that you are adding is space issue.
your are giving space before bostonfile.csv
ie sample

```
project/data anaylysis/ bostonfile.csv
```

just remove space before bostonfile.csv it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the spaces on your directory. Also try changing the format of your directory.

```
Bostondata = pd.read_csv(r"C:\directory\folder\location")
```

I was having issues with opening a file earlier and saw a few ways to work it out.