# Pip list to show packages installed through pipenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` to manage virtual environments but I'm confused about the following.

If I run:

1. `pipenv shell`
2. `pip list` (or `pip3 list`)

I don't get the modules installed in the virtual environment (or those installed globally), it just prints: pip, setuptools, and wheel.

It finds the right packages when running the code and I can see them in the Pipfile, but shouldn't they show when running `pip list`?

Any clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate from this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961926/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-a-certain-virtualenv). Take a look at it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a list of installed packages in a certain virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961926/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-a-certain-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no it doesn't answer my question. As I said, if I want to check what the installed modules are, I can just open the Pipfile. My confusion is about the behavior of `pip list` here. I thought this would return all the modules in the virtual environment but it doesn't.

Comment: Only way I can see your method going wrong is if the activated venv (through pipenv shell) is a different venv than the one you want the deps from.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `pipenv graph` to show installed dependencies tree

Answer (score 0):

Type `pipenv run pip freeze` after activating pipenv with `pipenv shell`

Comment: I know there are other ways of getting the installed packages (as I said, I can do this from the Pipfile), my question is about the behavior of `pip list`.

Comment: This would only work if you have a venv installed in _another_ venv.