# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snscrape'

Tags: python

I have previously installed the 'snscrape' module but when I try to run the code I still get an error

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
> 2 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snscrape'

Any solution ?

Comment: are you using a virtual environment? if you are check if the module is installed on your virtual environment. [make a list of installed packages in a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961926/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-a-certain-virtualenv)

Comment: sometimes my IDE does that and it works if i restarted (if you installed it while running the IDE) but we may need more info to help

Comment: Have you tried `pip install snscrape`