# pip listing global packages in active virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

After upgrading pip from 1.4.x to 1.5 `pip freeze` outputs a list of my globally installed (system) packages instead of the ones installed inside of my virtualenv. I've tried downgrading to 1.4 again but that does not solve my problem. It's somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552631/pip-requirements-outputting-global-packages) only it's been working as expected for months. Is there any way to debug and/or repair this?

It seems like the virtualenv has no effect at all. Installing packages within it installs them globally too.

Comment: what is output of `which pip`? is it global pip or local to virtualenv?

Comment: @alko `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: @alko So I guess that's my problem ...

Comment: I know this question is specifically about virtualenv but if you use venv (`python3 -m venv myVirtualEnvironment`) this issue does not exist. For most, I doubt there is a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems with pip installing packages globally instead of in the activated virtualenv too. Have a look at [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) for the question (and the answer).

Basically, the solution consisted of modifying the shebang of the pip scripts within the virtualenv as they pointed to the wrong python installation.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have installed properly, but with global site packages visible to your `virtualenv`, still `pip` will list everything, unless you use `pip list --local` [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661035/1959808).

Comment: That just doesn't seem to be true. I think it's only true if you create the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`?? I ended up removing and recreating the virtualenv from scratch.

Comment: According to [`pip` documenentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_list.html#cmdoption-l) it *is* true, and it works correctly. Of course it is true **only** if you have created a `virtualenv` with `--system-site-packages`. This is what "but with global site packages visible" refers to in my answer. The "but" contrasts to the default `virtualenv` creation (by [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), which is isolated from global site packages.