# can't install local packages in python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

After the last update for my windows when I try to display the installed packages in python virtualenv
by

```
pip freeze --local
```

or

```
pip freeze
```

they gave me the same result "all globally installed packages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my pip package then it's work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtualenv activated?
`.\env\Scripts\activate`

After activating your virtualenv
`pip freeze --local > requirements.txt`

More can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: hmm. In that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017012/pip-listing-global-packages-in-active-virtualenv) might help

Comment: thanks a lot for you I realize where the problem may be to be
and update pip package again and its work fine

Comment: OK. Glad you figured it out!